# Consumer expecting response of List<String> using pact

Tags: java, junit, pact

I am creating pact consumer contract like this

```
  private RequestResponsePact createConsumerContract(final PactDslWithProvider pactDslWithProvider,
      final String path,
      final String query,
      final String state,
      final String description,
      final HttpStatus status,
      final DslPart expectedResponseBody,
      final String mediaType) {

    final Map<String, String> responseHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    responseHeaders.put("Content-Type", mediaType);

    return pactDslWithProvider.given(state)
        .uponReceiving(description)
        .path(path)
        .query(query)
        .method("GET")
        .headers("Accept", mediaType)
        .willRespondWith()
        .status(status.value())
        .headers(responseHeaders)
        .body(new PactDslJsonBody().eachArrayLike())
        .toPact();
  }
```

And the consumer is expecting the response as `List<String>`

How can i specify the response body in pact consumer contract.

Comment: Just wondering, what is the signature of that method you "return" from? And: Arrays.asList() doesnt do what you want?

Comment: @GhostCat Its List<String>

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
PactDslJsonArray.arrayEachLike(PactDslJsonRootValue.stringType("some example string"))
```